# JOptionPane component seems differ

Tags: java, arrays, drop-down-menu, scrollbar, joptionpane

When I use the following code the look of the JOptionPane seems to differ depending on how many items of data are held within the array. Sometimes a drop down scrolling list (similar to a JComboBox). At other times, when the array holds more items, a component similar to a JList.

```
Object wid = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Choose Width",
                    "Select a Width", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    null, width, "9");
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated as to how to control which type of component is displayed, and its look in terms of size and colours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the method `showInputDialog` you have no control how the dialog
is constructed or designed. This method exists to have a quick way to construct an input
dialog that works when you don't care how it looks or behaves.
It all depends on the look an feel of the environment. 
Mostly that means in this case
19 elements or lower result in a `JComboBox` and 20 or more result in a `JList`.
If you want to have full control of the GUI components you need to design them for yourself.
It is not as hard as it sounds. Have a look at this code. It will always result in a combo box no matter how much items it has.

```
final int items = 100;

// create items
String[] width = new String[items];
for(int i = 0; i < items; i++) width[i] = Integer.toString(i);

// create the panel
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
JLabel label = new JLabel("Choose Width");
JComboBox<String> cmbBox = new JComboBox<>(width);
cmbBox.setSelectedIndex(8);
panel.add(label);
panel.add(cmbBox);

// show dialog
int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel,
            "Select a Width", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null);

// get selection
if(res == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
    String sel = String.valueOf(cmbBox.getSelectedItem());
    System.out.println("you selected: " + sel);
}
```

Comment: First of all many thanks!
May I ask why you used showConfirmDialog instead of showInputDialog?
What is the difference between them? When should I use each other?

Comment: Try it and you will see the difference. inputDialog will create an additional textfield no matter if you use your own input elements in custom panel. So I recommend the confirmDialog because it creates no additional components.